# Adding code for App Transport Security Xcode 7.0.1 doesn't work

Tags: ios9, xcode7, nsapptransportsecurity

So I go to Game-Info.plist -->Open As --> Source Code

At end of source code I add:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
```

I then click on Game-Info.plist -->Open As -->Property List

What was added is --> Required device capabilities Array 2 items

NSAppTransportSecurity, never appears in Game-Info.plist Property list.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I even need this NSAppTransportSecurity? The only time http is used is my SLComposeViewController Facebook/Twitter share buttons. Plus I never received the message for App Transport Security in debug area.